# how to search and replace content of a file ,starting from a specific line number in bash

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I have the below file .

```
$ cat testfile
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
$
```

I need to search and replace all the strings 'line' with 'LINE' from the line number 2 till the end . I tried like below

```
 $sed '2 s/line/LINE/g' testfile
 line 1
 LINE 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
 line 6
 $
```

But my required output is :

```
line 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
LINE 4
LINE 5
LINE 6
```

$

How can I achieve it with sed command alone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# sed '2,$ s/line/LINE/g' /tmp/testfile 
line 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
LINE 4
LINE 5
LINE 6
```

`2,$` denotes from second line to end.

Comment: Thanks @fazlin ..This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
sed '2,$s/line/LINE/g' file
```

I suggest you reading the man/info page of sed, the "address" part.

Answer (score 0):

see: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html

```
sed '2,$ s/line/LINE/' testfile
```

If you want to change the file in-place (using -i parameter with sed) I recommend ed instead of sed.

```
echo -e '2,$ s/line/LINE/\nw' | ed -sv testfile
```